# Is $K[x_1, x_2,...]$ normal or not?

Tags: commutative-algebra

As the title speaks for itself, is the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables over a field normal or not?

Can someone provide a reference/proof? Thanks

Also, what about a directed union of normal subrings? Is that normal?

Tangential to this, what's a criterion for an element in $K[x_{1},x_{2},\ldots]$ to be nilpotent? We know that in $K[x]$ we have that $f$ is nilpotent if and only if the coefficients are nilpotent and similarly in finitely many variables. Does that hold in our case too?

Comment: Since your ring is the union of polynomial rings in finitely many variables, you should have no trouble fescribing the nilpotent elements!

Comment: Likewise for normality, really. It would be best if you told us what you did and explained where you goy stuck.

Comment: For the question about normality, as a hint note that any element of the fraction field $K(X_1,...)$ will be an element of $K(X_1,...,X_N)$ for some $N$. Similarly, any polynomial with coefficients in $K[X_1,...]$ will be a polynomial with coefficients in $K[X_1,...,X_M]$ for some $M$.

Comment: Dear @Mariano, when you write "where you goy stuck", are you blaming the OP for not being Jewish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is an UFD (unique factorization domain), then $R$ is integrally closed (see [here](http://planetmath.org/UFDsAreIntegrallyClosed.html)). The polynomial rings in finitely many indeterminates are UFDs. Moreover, $K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]$ is also an UFD (why?), so it is integrally closed.

A direct union of integrally closed rings is integrally closed.

*Remark.* If $K$ is a field, as I suppose to be, then $K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]$ is an integral domain and its only nilpotent element is $0$. In general, if $K$ is a commutative ring, then you have the same criterion as for the polynomial rings in finitely many indeterminates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, everything is clear; I forgot that UFDs are normal

Answer (score 0):

Since the polynomial ring in finitely many variables over a field is a UFD, it is normal.
Hence it suffices to prove that a directed union of normal subrings is normal.

Let $A$ be a directed union of a family of normal subrings $(A_i)_{i \in I}$.
Since every $A_i$ is an integral domain, $A$ is also an integral domain.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Suppose $\alpha \in K$ is integral over $A$.
There exists $c_1, \cdots, c_n \in A$ such that $\alpha^n + c_1\alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n = 0$.
$\alpha$ can be wriiten as $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a, b \in A$.
Since $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is directed, there exists $i \in I$ such that $a, b, c_1,\dots,c_n \in A_i$.
Hence $\alpha$ is contained in the field of fractions of $A_i$ and it is integral over $A_i$.
Since $A_i$ is normal, $\alpha \in A_i$.
Hence $A$ is normal.